# Why Do I need Range(Len)) for a nested if?

Tags: python

This works as is but when I didn't have range(len..)) in and do  `for i in arr` and `for j in arr`, I get `IndexError: list index out of range` on the if statement. Why is this?

```
arr = [2,2,2,2,4,5,2,45,3,4,4]

mostFrq = 0
mostFrqAmount = 0

for i in range(len(arr)):

        amountOfCurrent = 0

        # now look at temp element
        for j in range(len(arr)):
                if (arr[j] == arr[i]):
                        amountOfCurrent = amountOfCurrent + 1

        if (amountOfCurrent > mostFrqAmount):
                mostFrqAmount = amountOfCurrent
                mostFrq = arr[i]

print(mostFrq)
print(mostFrqAmount)
```

Comment: Because one of the items is `45`.  Since there aren't enough numbers in the list, that would raise an error.

Comment: By the way, you should consider using [`collections.Counter(arr).most_common(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you analyze what is going on with your code in the failing form, you have:

```
arr = [2,2,2,2,4,5,2,45,3,4,4]

mostFrq = 0
mostFrqAmount = 0

for i in arr:

        amountOfCurrent = 0

        # now look at temp element
        for j in arr:
                if (arr[j] == arr[i]):
                        amountOfCurrent = amountOfCurrent + 1

        if (amountOfCurrent > mostFrqAmount):
                mostFrqAmount = amountOfCurrent
                mostFrq = arr[i]

print(mostFrq)
print(mostFrqAmount)
```

Using the `for i in arr` form is returning an iterator that is handling the index information for you you, so your "i" is set to the values in your array.

When you get to this line:
    `if (arr[j] == arr[i]):`

you end up with the variable substitution of `arr[45]`

Your index of the array only goes to 10, so, you have the error thrown.

Comment: Duh I should've known.... `for i in is value`

and `for i in range(len(arr)) is index`

Answer (score 0):

When you're iterating over a list, you get its elements. Since you're then accessing list elements at the index of that element, it won't work when it's out of bounds (and wouldn't do what you expected anyways).

Instead, just use the items you're provided by the loop:

```
mostFrq = 0
mostFrqAmount = 0

for i in arr:
        amountOfCurrent = 0

        # now look at temp element
        for j in arr:
                if (j == i):
                        amountOfCurrent += 1

        if (amountOfCurrent > mostFrqAmount):
                mostFrqAmount = amountOfCurrent
                mostFrq = i
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've tried. This should work the same way:

```
arr = [2,2,2,2,4,5,2,45,3,4,4]

mostFrq = 0
mostFrqAmount = 0

for i in arr:

        amountOfCurrent = 0

        # now look at temp element
        for j in arr:
                if (j == i):
                        amountOfCurrent = amountOfCurrent + 1

        if (amountOfCurrent > mostFrqAmount):
                mostFrqAmount = amountOfCurrent
                mostFrq = i

print(mostFrq)
print(mostFrqAmount)
```